# sklearn ImportError: cannot import name stable_cumsum

Tags: python, scikit-learn, anaconda

I want to import StratifiedKFold from sklearn to do cross validation. My computer uses scikit-learn 0.18. 
In the python console, I type:

```
 from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold
```

The following error message pops up:

```
  File "<ipython-input-307-7880cb661350>", line 1, in <module>
    from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold

  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from ._split import BaseCrossValidator

  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_split.py", line 35, in <module>
    from ..gaussian_process.kernels import Kernel as GPKernel

  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\sklearn\gaussian_process\__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    from .gpr import GaussianProcessRegressor

  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\sklearn\gaussian_process\gpr.py", line 15, in <module>
    from sklearn.gaussian_process.kernels import RBF, ConstantKernel as C

  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\sklearn\gaussian_process\kernels.py", line 30, in <module>
    from ..metrics.pairwise import pairwise_kernels

  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from .ranking import auc

  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\ranking.py", line 30, in <module>
    from ..utils.extmath import stable_cumsum

ImportError: cannot import name stable_cumsum
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem has been solved:

remove scikit-learn:

```
conda remove scikit-learn
```

then reinstall it:

```
pip install -U scikit-learn
```

Comment: you'd better reinstall it using `conda` rather than `pip`

Comment: I'm still seeing this issue after uninstalling and reinstalling both using conda and pip

Comment: @bradden_gross Try restarting your environment (e.g. Spyder), that worked for me.